# Crystal Reports - Disable default rounding/Show all decimals

Tags: crystal-reports, decimal, crystal-reports-xi

If I create a Formula Field A containing only 1/1000 and then drag it out into the report it will show "0,00" due to default number of decimals is set to 1.00 and default rounding is set to 0.01 for a field of with the type Number. 
No problems. 
When decimals and rounding are adjusted it will show 0,001.

When I create Formula Field B that only contains {@A} and increase decimals and rounding it will show as "0,001000000000".

But if I use A to create a text, totext({@A}) + ' test', the result will be "0,00 test" and I can not figure out a way to show the correct "0,001 test" without adding totext({@A},3). I don't want to use rounding because the number of decimals in A varies and I don't want to show any zeroes at the end.

I did modify this code (could be used in conditional formatting of decimals for a number field):

```
If CurrentFieldValue = Int(CurrentFieldValue) Then    0
Else If CurrentFieldValue * 10 = Int(CurrentFieldValue * 10) Then 1
Else If CurrentFieldValue * 100 = Int(CurrentFieldValue * 100) Then 2
Else If CurrentFieldValue * 1000 = Int(CurrentFieldValue * 1000) Then 3
Else If CurrentFieldValue * 10000 = Int(CurrentFieldValue * 10000) Then 4
Else DefaultAttribute
```

to

```
If {@A}= Int{@A} Then totext({@A},0)
Else If {@A}* 10 = Int{@A}* 10) Then totext({@A},1)
...
```

It works but I was hoping I wouldn't need all that extra code, I already have performance issues in my Crystal Reports and I don't want the risk of adding to that.

I just want to use the actual value in {@A} no matter the number of decimals.
I guess this could be caused by both default rounding settings as default number of decimals
And now I realise this might be caused by default number of decimals, not rounding.

If I change A to (1/1000)*6 it will show up as 0,01 unformatted, B will show "0,00600000 test". So it is a rounding problem.

Answer (score 2):

- Leave the output of your desired formula as a number.
- Right click on the formula and select format field.
- In the number tab select Custom Style and click customize.
- For rounding option select 0.0000000001
- Click the X-2 next to the Decimals option and enter this formula

local numbervar a;
local numbervar b;

```
for a := 1 to 10 do
(
if mid(strreverse(totext(CurrentFieldValue,10)),a,1) <> "0" then 
    (b := a;
    a := 10);
);
11- b
```

Comment: I cant figure out why the code isnt pasting properly but local numbervar a; local numbervar b; should be the first two lines of the formula

Comment: That is a very similar solution to the conditional formatting example above. I was hoping for some sort of setting that would force Crystal Reports to use the actual value in the Formula Field

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the default rounding is defined by your system regional settings. If you increase the number of decimal places from 2 (usual) to say 8, all your problems will be resolved.